# Prove $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (0, \frac{1}n)= \emptyset $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is the proof I have written:

Suppose $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (0, \frac{1}n)\neq \emptyset $. Let $S=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (0, \frac{1}n)$. Then let $x\in S$, so $x>0$. By Archimedean Principle we have $\frac{1}N <x$ **so** $x\notin (o, \frac{1}N)$. So $x\notin \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (0, \frac{1}n)$ which is a contradiction. Thus,  $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (0, \frac{1}n)= \emptyset $.

My professor said I am very close but I need to prove the **so** part. It thought that was included with the Archimedean Principle? What else would I have to add to make it a complete proof?

Comment: Seems fine to me? My only thought is that your professor maybe wants you to work rigorously with the notion of "$\in$", i.e. to give some explicit statement like "$x \in (0,1/N)$ for some $N$ iff $0 < x$ and $x < 1/N$, thus $x > 1/N$ implies that $x \notin (0, 1/N)$". Seems a bit contrived though.